# Center a scrollable InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios

All,

I have a scrollable InputAccessoryView attached to my UITextView.
This was created as follows:

- create a UIScrollView
- add a horizontal UIStackView.
- Attach top, bottom, trailing, leading of stack view to scroll view.
- Set equal heights between stack and scroll.
- Insert lots of buttons into stack view.
- set TextView.inputaccessoryview = scrollview.

Voila! (Note - only the last line was programmatic).

So this works fine and correctly scrolls when the content (stack view) is wider than keyboard, BUT when you rotate to landscape (or run on an iPad), it is left aligned.

I'd like the buttons to be centred when the keyboard is wider than the set of buttons.

I've tried embedding the Scrollview into a UIView with Center X, but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone give me some pointers?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
The answer is to use ContentInset on the scrollbar (which is the InputAccessoryView above). The specific code is:

```
public void CentreToolbar()
{
    var offsetX = Math.Max((scrollView.Bounds.Width - scrollView.ContentSize.Width) / 2, 0);
    scrollView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, (nfloat)offsetX, 0, 0);
}
```

This code should be called anytime the layout of the screen changes - such as during rotation.